# webarchive in iphone

Tags: iphone, webarchive

can we use webarchive in iphone to display Pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebArchive format is not supported on iPhone. To display a PDF in a UIWebView, simply load the PDF; UIWebView can display it automatically as it would an HTML file or a website.

Comment: iPad uses the same APIs as iPhone (for the most part.) So no, not there either.